# Rename Solution containing more than 1 projects in vs2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, solution

In my solution i have three projects

1. SIRE
2. SIREWebServiceClient
3. SIREWebUIModelClasses

the sln file is in 1st project SIRE.sln

Now i want to rename my projects name to

1. OMS_WebSolution
2. OMS_WebServiceClient
3. OMS_WebUIModelClasses
   and the sln file to OMS.sln

i tried every thing but unable to load 1 or 2 projects after renaming

i even tried this steps

a. Close the solution and the IDE

b. In Explorer: Change the directory name to the new name.

c. In Explorer:  Open the .sln file with a text editor.

c. Change the directory name to the new name and save.

d. Restart the IDE and open the solution from the File, Recent Files menu if it doesn't start automatically.

e. Click on the Project folder of the Solution Explorer and check the path property in the properties at the bottom. It will now be referencing to the new project folder.

only one project get loaded rest unavailable
any help will be highly appreciable Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating a new solution and adding the existing, now-renamed projects to it?

Comment: ya i tried but it does not completely work